# DOS Attack mitigation/rate limiting on SAP BTP CF Apps Apis

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform

I am developing Side by side extension application on SAP BTP Cloud foundry environment ,application business api's are provided by Java microservices on frontend via SAP CF Approuter, my requirement is to capture certain malicious activity by logged in user in terms of flooding the services calls via some BOT via some rate limiting or DOS attack prevention mechanism ,**is there any way SAP BTP CF environment can handle this requirement by design or through some settings for the underlying applications build on top of it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SAP BTP has built in support to protect applications from Denial of Service (DoS) attacks.

SAP BTP uses below security features to safeguard applications against DoS attacks :

- Rate limiting
- Auto-scaling
- Network protection

Apart from that , SAP BTP provides cloud infrastructure security measures and network protection against malicious traffic, helping to prevent DoS attacks. However, the exact features and the level of protection may vary depending on the specific SAP BTP service used.

Answer (score 0):

SAP BTP Cloud Foundry does, unfortunately, not provide any built-in mechanism to protect your application from misuse in form of Denial of Service (DOS) attacks at this point in time.

That said, you would need to either implement a rate limiter yourself, or take advantage of an existing solution (such as the [Spring Cloud Zuul RateLimit](https://github.com/marcosbarbero/spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit)).